# Можно ли накопить update/insert-запросы, чтобы потом разом их выполнить их через updateAll/batchInsert?

Tags: yii2

**Проблема**: есть функции, которые одновременно изменяют >10 000 записей в БД.

Работает это примерно так:

```
foreach($query->each() as $item) {
  $item->sold();
  $item->save(false);
}
```

Из-за такой "поштучной" обработки — процесс изменения *идёт довольно медленно*.
Конечно, можно использовать batchUpdate(Model::updateAll()). Но здесь возникает проблема **DRY**, поскольку мы больше не можем использовать больше метод `$item->sold()`, который выглядит так:

```
public function sold()
    {
        $this->changeStatus(self::STATUS_SOLD, time());
        $this->whole_cost = $this->product->price;
    }
```

Нам нужно писать аналогичную функцию для массовой продажи:

```
public function batchSold($itemsId, $wholeCost)
{
    return ProductItem::updateAll(['status' => $status, 'whole_cost' => $wholeCost];
}
```

Как *следствие*, при изменении метода `sold()` кто-то может забыть поправить `batchSold()`, что произведет(а если точнее — уже произвело) к багам. Не говоря уже о побочных эффектах при использовании Event.

**Вопрос**: Можно ли "накопить" update-запросы, не выполняя их фактически, чтобы потом упаковать в batchUpdate и выполнить разом? Если да, то как?

Comment: "кто-то может забыть поправить batchSold()" --- можно в batchSold использовать sold и тогда никто ничего не забудет... потому что чисто логически "помыть 100 чашек" это "помыть одну чашку", только 100 раз.......а так, можно подключить очередь типа rabbitMQ и дать ей всю работу сделать.

Comment: Вероятно похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477678/yii2-updateall-with-multi-conditions

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а как `sold()` использовать в `batchSold()`? Собственно, в вопросе два оригинальных метода — если знаете, как можно соеденить, то покажите, пожалуйста.


P.S. RabbitMQ уже используется, но это всё же не влияет на скорость выполнения операции: тех же изменений в 10 000 записях.